# C#: How to hash a string into RIPEMD160

Tags: c#, security, hash

For example the password is "Hello World", How can I make it return to a RIPEMD160 Hash String? It is supposed to return a string: "a830d7beb04eb7549ce990fb7dc962e499a27230". I searched already the internet for the answer to my question but instead of a string the code is about encrypting a file to RIPEMD160.

Answer (score 2):

OK I already know the solution to the problem. Convert the string to a byte, pass it to RIPEMD160 function, Create a StringBuilder and pass the returned byte of the RIPEMD160 function, Convert the returned StringBuilder to string and once again convert it to lower case. I created a function for it. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Password
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string thePassword = "Hello World";
            string theHash = getHash(thePassword);
            Console.WriteLine("String: " + thePassword);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Hash: " + theHash);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static string getHash(string password)
        {
            // create a ripemd160 object
            RIPEMD160 r160 = RIPEMD160Managed.Create();
            // convert the string to byte
            byte[] myByte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
            // compute the byte to RIPEMD160 hash
            byte[] encrypted = r160.ComputeHash(myByte);
            // create a new StringBuilder process the hash byte
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(encrypted[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            // convert the StringBuilder to String and convert it to lower case and return it.
            return sb.ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `ToString("x2")`, you don't need to convert it to lower case.